# wpf textbox content freezes ui on load

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, textbox

I started coding my first WPF app and I'm having trouble with a textbox that displays some system info (cpu, memory, disk usage, mac address, etc.).
My apps has navigation between two pages and the said textbox is on one of the pages. The textbox's content is retrieved via WMI queries.
The issue I have noticed is that while navigating to tha page with the textbox it freezes the UI for about two seconds before going to and display the page.
I'm a newbie and my best guess is that eighter the WMI queries(could be badly coded too) are doing that or I'm loading the content in the textbox wrongfully.
An example of how my queries are constructed

```
public string getCPU()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
        ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (ManagementObject wmi in searcher.Get())
        {
            try
            {
                sb.Append("Processor: " + wmi.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch
            {
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public string getRAMsize()
    {
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
        foreach (ManagementObject item in moc)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(item.Properties["TotalPhysicalMemory"].Value) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024), 0)) + " GB";
        }

        return "RAMsize";
    }
```

And this is what I use to retrieve the data in the textbox:

```
private void TextBox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = getCPU();
        TextBox1.Text += "Memory:  " + getRAMsize() + Environment.NewLine;
        TextBox1.Text += "Free Space:  " + GetTotalFreeSpace(sysdrive) + " GB" + Environment.NewLine;
        if (Is64BitSystem)
        {
            TextBox1.Text += getOS() + " 64bit" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Text += getOS() + " 32 Bit" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        TextBox1.Text += "MAC Address : " + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(GetMacAddress().ToString(), ".{2}", "$0 ") + Environment.NewLine;
        TextBox1.Text += av();
    }
```

My question is what am I doing wrong and how can I get around with it. In my mind , if the queries are constructed correctly, it would be because they are done again and again everytime the textbox is loaded (on navigation or at startup) and maybe If I could get it to load only once and remember those values(since most of the data should stay the same).
But as I said I'm a noob and any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking each and every query I found out that the getCPU one is causing a delay in the load.
I replaced it with a Registry.GetValue, wich is very fast.
Thanks to Sebastian L, because altough his code didn't work for me it put me on the right path and I was able to adapt own code with a backgroundworker to avoid UI freeze of any kind
my working code:

```
private void TextBox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate (object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {

        });
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(delegate (object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0", "ProcessorNameString", null) + Environment.NewLine;
            TextBox1.Text += "Memory:  " + getRAMsize() + Environment.NewLine;
            TextBox1.Text += "Free Space:  " + GetTotalFreeSpace(sysdrive) + " GB" + Environment.NewLine;
            if (Is64BitSystem)
            {
                TextBox1.Text += getOS() + " 64bit" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox1.Text += getOS() + " 32 Bit" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            TextBox1.Text += "MAC Address : " + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(GetMacAddress().ToString(), ".{2}", "$0 ") + Environment.NewLine;
            TextBox1.Text += av();
        });
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are aquiring your data in the UI Thread.

You should load the data in the background thread and then, since you use wpf, binding the textbox text to a variable.

Example (This code is Copy'n'Paste ready):

```
// INotifyPropertyChanged is an Interface which enables binding of Properties in your window
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _systemInformation;

    // Stub (works actually)
    private bool is64BitSystem = (IntPtr.Size == 8);

    // Stub
    private string sysdrive = "YOLO\\:";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Set Datacontext normally set to a viewmodel but ther is none in this code
        this.DataContext = this;

        // The Backgroundworker does things in the background (nonblocking)
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += DoItButDontInterruptMeDuh;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string SystemInformation { get => _systemInformation; set => _systemInformation = value; }

    //Stub
    public string getCPU()
    {
        return "Fancy CPU";
    }

    //Stub
    public string getRAMsize()
    {
        return "1 PB";
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    //Stub
    private string av()
    {
        return "Whatever av means.";
    }

    private void DoItButDontInterruptMeDuh(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Simulate loading time
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        SystemInformation = getCPU();
        SystemInformation += "Memory:  " + getRAMsize() + Environment.NewLine;
        SystemInformation += "Free Space:  " + GetTotalFreeSpace(sysdrive) + " GB" + Environment.NewLine;
        if (is64BitSystem)
        {
            SystemInformation += getOS() + " 64bit" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else
        {
            SystemInformation += getOS() + " 32 Bit" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        SystemInformation += "MAC Address : " + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(GetMacAddress().ToString(), ".{2}", "$0 ") + Environment.NewLine;
        SystemInformation += av();
        OnPropertyChanged("SystemInformation");
    }

    //Stub
    private object GetMacAddress()
    {
        return "Macintoshstreet 1234";
    }

    //Stub
    private string getOS()
    {
        return "Cool OS";
    }

    //Stub
    private string GetTotalFreeSpace(object sysdrive)
    {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

and in the .xaml:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Path=SystemInformation}/>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show how to run the tasks in the background thread also you should point out that any attempt to manipulate UI element from background thread will result in an exception being thrown. As the UI elements are NOT thread safe. Also your xaml is not correct.

Comment: Please, more noob friendly. Do I have to create a new class called SomeWindow (or SysInfo) ? what is InitWhatever(); supposed to be(same doesn't exist in current context)? NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => systemInformation); throws exception : doesn't exist in current context

Comment: many thanks, but still got 1 exception : Type 'MainWindow' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types

Comment: probabily my bad since I pasted the code in a new class file and that's why it was throwin that exception. Moved the code in the MainWindow.cs file and the exception is gone...still textbox doesn't load the content.

Comment: very sorry, but the code is not correct. even if i correct the xaml code to Text="{Binding Path=SystemInformation}" as it should be the textbox doesn't load any content. as already menitioned the texbox is not contained on the main window, it actually located on a page called home.xaml wich happens to be the default page displayed inside a frame of main window. maybe binding doesn't work this way?

Comment: This code is working, you can download the project here: https://github.com/hrkrx/WPF-Bindings-SO- 
still you sure need to adapt the code for your project

Comment: well, it doesn't work for me, sorry. forgot to mention that my target framework is and needs to be 3.5 … maybe that's why it's not working?

Comment: if you are unable to adapt this into your project, i am very sorry, but then i am unable to help you, since we are not here to do your work for you.